# Choosing a 32-bit microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller

Now that most vendors offer a diverse variety of ARM Cortex-M chips, why would one pick a Renesas or Freescale product? I understand that there are reasons for somebody to go with a PIC32 as they are familiar with tools etc, there also reasons to use a 16 or 8 bit MCU from TI or Atmel as they might think it's somewhat more suitable for their design, but why would one want to use a Renesas RX or Freescale ColdFire?

Comment: If the volume is large enough, even moderate factors that make a particular chip (including it's peripherals) more suitable or cost effective for a task can justify dealing with a new software architecture.  Also, those other designs aren't necessarily new architectures anyway - many of the coldfire devices are 68000 family descendants.

Comment: I usually look at peripherals and price.

Comment: Damn, I had a feeling this will get downvoted ;~(

Comment: @errordeveloper: don't get discouraged by downvotes, especially not one.

Comment: somewhat related thread: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/37423/how-to-choose-a-mcu-platform , although it deals with a wider set of choices

Answer (score 10):

I think the best answer to this question, which gets asked a lot, is to look at a good survey. Embedded has a very good survey and it includes many factors.

Look at it and you can see many of the factors motivating people:

[UBM Embedded Market Study 2012](http://www.embedded.com/ContentEETimes/Documents/Embedded.com/MarketStudy/2012_EmbeddedMarketStudy_UBM.pdf)

Some of the factors you mentioned, and many others are covered and reveal  a wide variety of factors play into the selection. Familiarity with the parts dominate, but the strength of the ecosystem is very important.