# What components do I need to wirelessly transmit a small signal via Bluetooth?

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

So I'm doing a project trying to create a wireless Electrocardiogram (ECG or EKG) system.  I built the hardware, connected it to a human subject, and it works perfectly - you can see the heartbeat well on an oscilloscope.  Here's a little more information on my signal:

Amplitude: ~800 mVpp
f < 30 Hz (and there are important frequencies that are ~ 1 Hz)

I am having a hard time choosing which IC to buy because there are so many to choose from, and I don't know which ones will satisfy my needs.  Let's assume I have a display that can receive the wireless signal and display it (i.e. a mobile phone with Bluetooth capabilities, and an oscilloscope app).  What specs should I be concerned about when looking at the spec sheets for the ICs?  Is a microcontroller necessary?

Comment: Most microcontrollers can do what you need. Sampling a 30hZ signal is not particularly hard. A 5 dollar bluetooth serial module provides most of the bluetooth. Just need to code the mcu and the app.

Comment: OP IS ASKING HOW TO SELECT A MICROCONTROLLER FOR HIS TARGET APPLICATION! COMPLETELY ON TOPIC FFS!

Comment: Here's my take on [what specs to consider when choosing a microcontroller](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/37435/7036).

Comment: Let's see, describe the situation and specific problem? Looks like the poster did exactly that. Why a question about integrated circuits and Bluetooth is marked off-topic on an electrical engineering site is far beyond me.  **Many** questions on this site become obsolete rather quickly simply due to the nature of the question. It's a nice guideline but is impossible to follow perfectly in practice and when it gets to the point where you prevent knowledgeable exchanges of useful information relating to electrical engineering from occurring, then that's being overbearing.

Comment: You may simply google for bluetooth data acquisition modules. There are many to choose from, simply match the specs/performance/price to your needs.

Comment: @krb686 the reason is, in order go find significance in life, people establish small kingdoms in these forums.  when surfing useful questions in stack exchange, i almost always *expect* them to be closed.