# How does one know if an 8 bit MCU is sufficient or 16 bit MCU is needed?

Tags: microcontroller, pic

16 bit micro controllers are more powerful than 8 bit ones and the 32 bit ones are on a whole different level. With that being said, while we can decided what peripherals we needed for an application and try to find the cheapest (and easy to use i.e the tool chain) alternative, how does one know if an 8 bit micro controller should be used for an application or a 16 bit one or a 32 bit one?

I do understand the differences between them so I will put the question in a different way.

Lets say I have an application in which I shall have an LCD display used to show bitmap image, a 16 key pad, buzzer, temperature and humidity sensor and a mouse input. A high end 8-bit micro controller can easily do all these things in real time. Now if I move to a colored LCD display, then I may need a 32 bit microcontroller that can update the colored display quickly enough and has more memory. However, I may only find out that my high end 8-bit microcontroller is weak, after I have tried it in the project.

So, before we start working on the project, how do we know what size and how much powerful microcontroller is needed for the project?

Comment: You should indeed make an estimation like you did already. Realtime/fast tasks often needs a MCU, image processing/advanced input/output (not-so-realtime) works better with an ARM.

Basically you could look on what projects Arduino has versus Raspberry Pi.
Though there even are 32-bit MCU's which can do pretty amazing stuff. Check what's important for your project, take something reasonable, you can always scale down if needed.

Answer (score 13):

Usually, the decision about the microcontroller is a balance between:

1. Special features (low power consumption, for example)
2. Development time.
3. Cost of goods in production.

If short development time has more priority than cost of goods, then go for the more muscular controller.  You can do cost optimization later as a separate stage.  Premature costoptimization [sic] often spoils projects.

If you are already in the cost optimization stage, then you start from a working product.  The early non-optimized version acts as a prototype for the optimized version.  The early version flushes out the requirements.

Related: [How to choose a MCU platform?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/37435/7036)

Comment: One wouldn't believe how universal is the **design-implement-review** chain (or cycle, if you wish).

Answer (score 6):

> before we start working on the project, how do we know what size and how much powerful microcontroller is needed for the project?

You can't know. And that's a big problem. If you choose a microcontroller that's too small, you might run out of resources (memory/pins/registers/other features) and these resources can be hard to accurately estimate until it's too late. But if you choose a microcontroller that's too large, you are paying for resources you aren't using, and that adds to the system cost.

You can sometimes make an educated guess how much of the various resources your application will need... if you were doing FFT calculations for example, you can calculate the exact amount of memory the samples will require. But it's harder to reliably determine how much object code space the software will require, until after it's been written.

A good hedge against running out of code memory, is to select a microcontroller family that is **scalable** across several different price/performance points. This is a big selling point of the **ARM**, **Microchip PIC**, **Atmel AVR**, and other scalable micro's. As you develop your software, you can move from a larger development system into a smaller target system, keeping the final end-product cost down.

Scalable means that all of the microcontrollers in that family have (mostly) the same instruction set and (mostly) the same registers. So software written for one, will work on another in the same family. (Microchip PIC code will not run on an ARM, but if you learn the PIC14 it's easy to move down to the PIC12 or up to the PIC16.)

If you're only building a one-off prototype, rather than a full production product line, your best option is to stick with a development system that's a bit larger than you think you need, but has room to grow.

Answer (score 3):

A big factor is the size of your most-often-used variables.  If you are using mostly 8-bit variables, and you only need to access 8-bit ports, then you can probably get by with a 8-bit MCU.

However if you have a lot of 16-bit variables, and even just a few 32-bit longs, then you are going to need to look at a 16-bit (or even 32-bit) MCU since accessing 16-bit variables with a 8-bit MCU takes a far amount of code.

And if you are going to use any floating point variables, I strongly suggest a 16-bit or 32-bit MCU.

Even if you don't have the time to write much of the code you will need to use, I suggest writing some of it beforehand and compiling for whatever microcontrollers you might be using.  Most microcontroller manufacturers have free versions of their compilers, perhaps limited by the size of the output file, or by limiting the amount of optimization.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, before you design a new board, you do a proof-of-concept project using either a development board (or any commercially available board) or a leftover board from one of your previous projects.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, 32bit MPUs are often faster due to a higher frequency, but also due to their capabilities or some 'tricks' they can do.

As said by @tcrosley, a 32bit MCU can add two 32bit integers in one go, while an 8bit MCU will have to to this byte by byte. Floating point numbers need at least 16 bit and their math is more complex, which means lots of work for the 8bit MCU. A 32bit MCU may do the math in hardware, so once again, in one go. One of the tricks may be to do four additions of 8bit variables at once. Load four 8bit values into the register, and add 8bit values to each of them.

But that's not all.
**Also have a careful look at the hardware periphery, which is not necessarily more powerful on 32bit MCUs!**
An experience:

At my university, we built an oscilloscope consisting of a PIC18F2550 (8bit, 10bit ADC, USB), an opamp to realize several voltage ranges and some caps & resistors. This was meant as very simple, very cheap oscilloscope for schools with a sample rate of... I guess it was about 50khz. Transfer was done via CDC for high compability.

When microchip came up with its PIC32 MCUs it looked promising. Price was almost the same, 120MInstructions/s instead of 12, high speed USB instead of full speed. The last point was interesting because throughput was  the limiting factor of the PIC18, and microchips benchmarks showed a remarkable higher USB throughput.

Finally, it turned out that the PIC18 did all the USB stuff in hardware, while the PI32 seems to do more in software - as soon as the PIC32 gets more work to do, the throughput dropped. Hence, we could not realize a faster oscilloscope with PIC32.

(I wasn't involved in this - so I don't know the details)

Answer (score 2):

Well, before you really start coding, you first have to do some research what you'll need to realize a project. That's part of the job.

If you're already familiar with microcontrollers, than do some research whether a 8-bit uC is sufficient or not. It depends on the complexity, whether it will be extended or not (like from a monochrome LCD to color LCD), is it for a long term, does it have to be low power consumption, low memory usage and so on...

I had to do some research about which ARM uC I had to choose and also which compiler (based on price and popularity). In my situation it was important to check the availability of peripherals.

So just a simple yes or no is not possible. So, welcome to the world of Engineering :)

Answer (score 1):

One word provides the answer - EXPERIENCE.

Till then you try things and learn to gain the experience.

Keep in mind also that there are tasks that you can set to an any MCU that may fall flat on their face if the wrong design approach is used for the algorithms. Long ago I coded firmware for a 4.9MHz 8-bit MCU that used clever algorithms and was able to monitor the on-hook / off-hook and detect ringing status by filtering for the ~20Hz ring voltage signal on all of 28 phone lines simultaneously and then report that status to a central control station all the while running a LCD display and operating a fairly complex user interface off of detected DTMF tones. Fun stuff.

Comment: I wish I could do things like that at my work