Choosing MCU for motor control
Suppose you have to choose an MCU to be used to drive an inverter and an electric motor (e.g., three-phase brushless AC) and have it soldered to the final pcb with connectors, mosfets ecc.
There are really a lot of MCU models online .. how do you choose the specifications of the MCU according to design criteria?
Do you choose the MCU based on the type of motor? Or maybe based on the type of control? Or to the type of inverter?
Doing a little research, it seems to me that the "necessary" specifications are:

have a timer that can generate 3 PWM signals (one per channel) and, possibly, with dead time generation and emergency stop
CAN bus, SPI or other communication protocols.
something with CMSIS yo performs Clark/Park transformations if needed
But surely there are many other things besides these...

If you have interesting papers/articles explaining this MCU "choice", please leave the link
Thanks so much

The one that has an evaluation board, the one that has lot of examples, good compiler, nice GUI and debug possibility,...I would also look for QEI unit or similar unit embedded, Freescale NXP, TI, Microchip (?), as far I know STM32 does not have a QEI, however it has a quadrature encoder up/down counter.

Does it have to be an MCU? For close loop motor control, if you need to interface some special encoders, there might not be suitable peripherals on any (common) MCUs. FPGA based SoC is a better choice then.

Looking at your requirements, there are lot of MCUs which meet your requirements.  Many 8bit and 16.32 bit MCUs have multiple PWM channels and a timer, CAN, SPI buses, watchdog timer,GPIOs and software support. I'm not familiar with CMSIS but it seems like a MCU manufacturer suggested software library support for all peripherals in a MCU. A 8bit CPU with a 40 Mhz clock speed, 10 dedicated PWM channels, 1 CAN, 1 SPI,watchdog timer, 10 GPIOs, 64 KB RAM and 128 KB flash and some software support like device drivers would be enough for this application. It is not bad to go for a higher CPU such as 16/32 bit MCU with higher specifications. A 48 or 64 PIN MCU would have all features you may require. MCUs come with different packaging with lesser/more features and with less or more pins.
Here are tips on how to select a MCU.
Go to a MCU manufacturer's website such as NXP, TI, ST, Infineon etc and select microcontroller selection tool which is a web based form which lets to choose a product. You might choose automotive or industrial for category of microcontrollers. Typically, all automotive MCUs have CAN and SPI while some industrial MCUs may not have CAN.
Links for choosing MCUs:

NXP: Product Selector
Texas Instruments: Microcontrollers (MCUs) & processors
STMicroelectronics: STM32 MCU product selector
Infineon Technologies: Microcontroller Finder

If you do a detailed search, you can find such selection tools.  When choosing a MCU, do proper requirements engineering to see what things are required. Ask yourself relevant questions such as:

How much clock speed?
How may pins? Each pin adds cost if a product is mass produced in tens to hundreds of thousands.
How much RAM?
How much FLASH?
How many timers? Does it have a watchdog timer?
How many PWM channels? Should they be synchronous with same phase or asynchronous with different phases?
How many CAN modules required?
How many SPI modules required?
How many ADCs are required and which ADC such as 10bit or 12bit is required?
How many GPIOs are required?
What motor control features are required?
What price you can pay? Typically such MCUs cost like $4 to $5 max per piece when bought as samples.
Is there any device driver, bootloader support for the MCU?
Is an RTOS required and which RTOS can fit this application?
Is there a compiler given or do it have to be bought separately? Which development and debugging tools are available for the MCU?
Is there a development board available from the manufacturer? Typically, a development or evaluation board if it exists for the MCU has the MCU you want with all the GPIO pins on the board. It is about the size of 7CMx5CM. Usually, many MCUs are similar and the development board may have a slightly different MCU which may fit your application. It is possible to prototype the application on the development board and order individual MCUs required separately to make a custom PCB.
How long would the MCU exist in production? What is its End of life? Typically, EOL for a MCU means that the MCU would not be produced anymore. However, other MCUs with similar and enhanced features would continue to exist.

If any product which suits these answers exists, that would be the MCU to choose in the application.

"How much clock speed?" That's pretty irrelevant without having the CPU ISA in mind. A crappy PIC clocked at 40MHz will severely underperform compared to a Cortex M0 clocked at 8MHz. There are no good arguments to stay in the 8/16 bit swamp, but plenty of arguments against it - the main one being that pretty much all 8/16 bit ISA on the market are completely outdated crap from the 1990s.

Thanks velvet. Yes, there seem many TI options for this too. I recall attending a TI exhibition on motor control in llinois and I even attended a "class" on motor control MCUs given by a engineer from TI or somewhere else in that event many years ago.

Similarly, "how much memory" doesn't make much sense either without a specific ISA in mind. Some 16 bitters in particular were pretty great at code density, but obviously if you do lot of 32 bit arithmetic then a 32 bit CPU will consume far less flash memory than any 8/16 bitter. Overall, if you write very pedantic hand-crafted C code without too much 32-bit arithmetic, then 32 bitters do tend to result in slightly larger programs though. On-chip flash isn't much of an issue any longer, it used to drive the price in the 2000s but that's no longer the case.

lundin,, I am not aware of microchip MCUs and how they perform. I was only familiar with freescale( now NXP), infineon, and ST MCUs. If you have any relevant data on comparison of CPU performance, you can post that as an answer.

It's based on practical experience over the years. I used to do lots of work on Freescale 8/16 bitters like the HC08 & HC12. They perform better than PIC16 etc but still they perform poorly due to the severely limited accumulator-based cores. Something 32 bit like Coldfire, Kinetis or MPC5x will obviously wastly outperform them. I haven't used S32 but that's apparently what they are pushing for currently. Either way, 8/16 bitters are a thing of the past - RIP - good riddance.

lundin, as for RAM,, for just three PWM channels and a watchdog timer, some interrupts, a CAN controller, 2KB to 8 KB should be enough. Flash size such as 64 KB is more than enough. A low end 8 bit MCU might be sufficient for this application. A mid range 16 bit MCU with 40 to 80 Mhz CPU and 24KB to 64 KB RAM and 64KB to 128 KB flash  may also be a future proof choice.

I disagree, there exists no reason why you'd ever use a part like that in 2024 when you can get a Cortex M0 32 bitter which is better at literally everything for $1. And unlike 8/16 bitters it is actually future proof. Speaking of NXP specifically, just look at how shamelessly they have raised the prices for 8/16 bitters. They want to get rid of these production lines.

If the application uses very few processors, then getting a 32 bit MCU with advanced motor control features may be better.

I haven't used such MCUs but I'd probably be skeptic about specifying one, since it would mean "marrying" the MCU vendor. On the other hand, using an external motor driver IC probably means marrying that vendor instead :)

This is one of the areas where it helps to have access to an experienced engineer, since picking MCU can be both overwhelming and subjective. Some hints for picking the correct MCU:

Write a proper and detailed product specification before you do anything else. Without a specification you can't do anything. Do not pick a MCU just because you happen to have one lying around. Re-using a familiar MCU between projects can save you a lot of time, but don't try to shoe-horn a familiar MCU into your current project when there are more suitable parts out there.
Try to determine the most exotic requirements and pick MCU based on those. For example 3 PWM channels is a super common requirement, as is SPI - literally any MCU can do that. CAN is a rarer requirement and may force you to look at automotive-flavoured parts. For example you'll notice that finding a small chip with few pins and CAN is pretty rare - usually you end up with LQFP48 or larger when you need CAN.
Pick a MCU which is a sound choice in general - some guidelines here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/416224/6102. For example it is quite senseless to pick anything smaller than a Cortex M since some 10+ years back, unless you have very specialized requirements.
Some well-known manufacturers are "red flag" ones with horrible support and/or horrible availability. With experience you'll learn who they are. If you want names to avoid, feel free to poke me in the EE chat. It may be somewhat geographic-dependent, with some companies having poor support in certain areas of the world. And some taking pride in being bad world-wide...


You'd pretty much use the same method you use for picking any microcontroller.  For motor control, the difference will lie on which peripherals you want or need.
Say, for example, you're building a bare-metal motor control system, and want as little glue logic between the motor/encoder system and the microcontroller system.  For this case, I'd try hard to find a microcontroller with a peripheral designed to count quadrature, and something with nifty feature enhancements on the CCP module that make it easier to drive h-bridges in fancy ways.
It's been some time since I've built a motor control system that was that low-level, but when I did, I ran to some of the Microchip options marketed for motor control (somewhat dated document at https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/00896f.pdf )
